# How to Add WYSIWYG Editor (tinyMCE) to plugin options page compatible with Wordpress 3.0 and up?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to add tinyMCE instead of textarea for one of my options in my plugin with no luck so far. I tried this :

http://www.dbuggr.com/smallwei/add-wysiwyg-editor-tinymce-wordpress-plugin/

and this:

http://blog.imwd8solutions.com/wordpress/wordpress-plugin-development-add-editor-to-plugin-admin-page/

There seems to be some problem with styles as styles for tabs (HTML style/Visual style) dont work. Anybody knows about implementation that works 100% with WP 3.0 and up ?

Answer (score 12):

Pre WP 3.3:
http://www.dev4press.com/2010/tutorials/wordpress/tips/add-rich-text-editor-to-your-plugin/

If you are using WP 3.3 or later you might look up wp_editor:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

```
$settings = array(
    'teeny' => true,
    'textarea_rows' => 15,
    'tabindex' => 1
);
wp_editor(esc_html( __(get_option('whatever_you_need', 'whatever'))), 'terms_wp_content', $settings);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php 
  function my_address_function(){

   if(isset($_POST['special_content'])){
     update_option('special_content', $_POST['special_content']);
   }

?>
<div class='wrap'>
  <h2>My Super Admin Page</h2>
    <form method='post'>
      <?php
          $content = get_option('special_content');
          wp_editor( $content, 'special_content', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=> '10') );

          submit_button('Save', 'primary');
       ?>
   </form>
  </div><!-- .wrap -->
 <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly:

wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

There's a checkbox in the options to show the custom styles of the theme.

Comment: unfortunately I need it for plugin I create, I don't want it to depend on any other plugin

Comment: me too need the same...