# How do I use jQuery to add the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to a textarea?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Using jQuery (as part of a theme or plugin) how can I add the WYSIWYG (TinyMCE) rich text editor to a `<textarea>`? Specifically, I want to activate it upon certain conditions being met (changes in the form etc.).

I have a timer event that checks the text size periodically for a number of reasons, this will be the function that activates the editor.

What do I need to do to make the TinyMCE available on a front end and attach/activate it as required? (looks like the user is writing a lot of text, activate TinyMCE). I assume there is something I need to enqueue but, beyond that, I'm just guessing.

My question is related to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29066/how-to-add-wysiwyg-editor-tinymce-to-plugin-options-page-compatible-with-wordp) but differs in that I want to do this with jQuery. Also related, [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29816/tinymce-in-a-div-textarea-on-frontend), but that's only a partial answer (I still need to know what to hook). I need to set it up and then activate with jQuery.

Comment: WordPress has an API for TinyMCE - [`wp.editor`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.editor).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you @SallyCJ.

Comment: @SallyCJ That solved my problem. If you want to add that as a fully answer, I will accept and close out this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the WordPress JavaScript API for TinyMCE — [`wp.editor`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.editor).

The steps in brief:

1. PHP: Enqueue the editor scripts (and styles) via [`wp_enqueue_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_editor/).
2. JS: Call `wp.editor.initialize()` from your script.

And do take note of this: (the "this function" refers to `wp.editor.initialize`)

> If this function does nothing, please make sure that
>   `wp.editor.getDefaultSettings` is a function.

Which means, if it's not a function, then while there are no errors thrown in the browser/console, the `textarea` will not be converted to a TinyMCE editor.